# Identifying who changes a data-source SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have this report when I deploy it it works.  I come in the next day and under the Data Sources tab in properties I notice the report is pointing to our Dev environment.  Now I know and double check that it is not coming from the solution as I have overwrite datasources equal to false, and there is only the one datasource in the project (named something completely different)

But what I also noted was when I change just the datasource on the report the  Modified Date and Modified By does not change.

So it begs the question, is there anywhere on the SSRS site or database that I can capture who and when a datasource for a report is changed?

We are currently using SSRS 2005

Answer (score 1):

Reportserver.dbo.Catalog has record of who first created and last modified any object on the server.

Comment: Thanks but this is the same data that appears on the website.  For example my modified date for my report is: 2014-03-03 13:53:39.883 which is when I deployed it, but I change the datasource back this morning about 9:30.  Today is 3/4/2014.  But I will continue to look in that database.

Comment: So what is interesting is the Catalog doesn't have a key to the DataSource table.  But the datasource table has a key to the Catalog Item, both for the report and the Datasource.  And there is no modification data on the datasource table.  I wonder if I can add a trigger to that table to log the date time/User of the change?

Comment: You absolutely could use a trigger.  You'll also find that pretty much all of the actions on the Report Manager portal have a stored procedure in ReportServer associated with them, so you could also easily just add an extra insert somewhere within.